# MySQL Linear Hash partitioning

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

MySQL uses a rather simple algorithm to assign keys to partitions:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-linear-hash.html

Basically, given *num* available partitions, and key *k*:

MySQL tries to assign the key *k* to partition "*k* modulo *V*", where *V* is the smallest power of 2 greater than the partition. 
If the output exceeds *num*, they repeatedly try with the next smaller power of 2: *k mod V/2*...

What I don't understand is why they need the loop: it seems they can stop at *V/2* and never need to consider *V/4*. 
Am I missing something, or is the doc making things more complex than they should be?

I am recalling the Mysql doc code below:

```
V = POWER(2, CEILING(LOG(2, num)))
N = F(k) & (V - 1)
While N >= num
{ V = V / 2 
  N = N & (V - 1)
}
Assign key k to N
```

Comment: May I ask why the close/negative vote? 
In the Help center, I read: if your question generally covers ... a software algorithm … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: Does hash `PARTITIONing` provide _any_ benefit to you?  Please tell me.  I have yet to find anyone with any benefit, especially for performance.

Comment: sry, I cant provide a real life use case there. I'm merely studying the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, and it is actually [calculated](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_partition.cc#L1378) without a loop:

```c
static uint32 get_part_id_from_linear_hash(longlong hash_value, uint mask,
                                           uint num_parts) {
  uint32 part_id = (uint32)(hash_value & mask);

  if (part_id >= num_parts) {
    uint new_mask = ((mask + 1) >> 1) - 1;
    part_id = (uint32)(hash_value & new_mask);
  }
  return part_id;
}
```

I am not entirely sure what the documentation wants to express, but since the implementation used in MySQL is a specific version of the more general linear hashing, the author probably just didn't simplify the more generic case (where you actually might use a loop) to the absolute end, or used a description from a whitepaper about the algorithm. And it's still correct.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I was not familiar enough with mysql to locate the source code. I should have thought about it, though. 
Funny, they mention a connection to linear hashing that I just argued against in another comment on stackoverflow. I'll have to amend. Anyway, thanks again.